# How to "break" a function we made?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, code-review

This is code about a keypad lock. The user can unlock the device by entering the secret code. To lock it again they press "#" or "*".

I want to let the green LED turn on for about 0.5 seconds then return to the first line of the loop: `char key = keypad.getKey();`.

The problem is that this code makes the green LED turn on forever after we enter the correct secret code or until we enter "#" or "*".

```
void loop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (key=='*'||key=='#') {
    position = 0;
    setLocked(true);
  }
  if (key==secretCode[position]) {
    position ++;
  }
  if (position ==3) {
    setLocked(false);
  }
  delay(100);
}

void setLocked(int locked) {
  if (locked) {
    digitalWrite(redpin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenpin, LOW);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(redpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenpin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `bool locked` instead of `int locked` in `setLocked` it's a waste of space.

Comment: @Avamander, doesn't gcc/gpp promote booleans to integers anyway?

Comment: @sa_leinad But by declaring it "bool" you let others know that it's either true or false. But if your point is right, it does indeed take away the "waste of space" argument. But by that logic you could better use a unsigned char, since it's an 8-bit platform.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that a Leonardo is 8-bit, so indeed no space will be saved by using bool instead of int this time but it's not a bad habit to have, to try and not waste space. @sa_leinad Yeah, both false and true have integer values and are treated in most cases as such.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something, but couldn't you just modify your `setLocked` function?

```
void setLocked(int locked) {
  if (locked) {
    digitalWrite(redpin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenpin, LOW);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(redpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenpin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(redpin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenpin, LOW);
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: I tried , but it returns to `setLocked` function, not ordinary loop.

Comment: @AntonyPossible I amended my answer. I'd put the return statement inside the `else` clause!

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at your `loop()` and it have some problems, like not counting how many digits did the user input and locking upon receiving a single "#" a

Here is some better way:

```
char secretCode[] = "1234";
char inputCode[] = "xxxx";
int position = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key == '*' || key=='#') {
    int i = 0;
    //  With 4 input digits, now we compare against secret code.
    while (i < sizeof(inputCode) && inputCode[i] == secretCode[i]) {
      i++;
      }
    //  Set locked only if 4 digits are the same.
    setLocked(i == sizeof(inputCode));
    //  Reset input code array.
    position = 0;
  } else {
    //  Key adding digits to the input code.
    inputCode[position++] = key;
    if (position == sizeof(inputCode)) {
      position = 0;
    }
  }  
  delay(100);
}

void setLocked(int locked) {
  if (locked) {
    digitalWrite(redpin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenpin, LOW);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(redpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenpin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(redpin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenpin, LOW);
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the device is unlocked with the correct code, you turn the green LED on wait for 0.5 seconds and then you don't turn it off again. So the simple answer would be [sempaiscuba's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/44146/19409).

Personally, I like the fact that the red LED indicates that the device is locked and the green LED indicates that it is unlocked.

The problem that I see with your code is that if the user enters an incorrect number, it doesn't reset, allowing any amount of wrong numbers until it sees the right number. This means that I could come along and press the keypay randomly and after a while I would have pressed every digit in the secret code and it would unlock.

Think of the problem as a state machine. You start with 0 digits correct (ie `position==0`). If at any time the user presses an incorrect digit (or the * or #), the state machine will reset back to 0 digits correct state. If the user enters the first digit correctly then it progresses to the 1 digit correct state (ie `position==1`). And so on until all of the digits are correct and the device is unlocked. Due to the simplicity of this state diagram it can be accomplished using a few if statements.

```C++
int position = 0;
char secretCode[] = "7890";
char inputCode[] = "????";      // This can be any character and just acts as a placeholder
boolean newKey = false;

void setup()
{
    setLocked(true);
}

void loop()
{
    char key = keypad.getKey();

    // Only process when a new key has been pressed 
    if ((key != NO_KEY) && newKey)
    {
      newKey = false;  // Don't enter this if statement again if the key is being held down (used for debounce)

      if ((key == secretCode[position]) && (position < 3))
      {
          // The correct key has been pressed 
          position ++;
          if (position == 3)
          {
            // Correct code has been entered (all 4 digits)
            setLocked(false);
          }
      }
      else
      {
        // It must be a wrong key (including * & #)
        // Or the device is unlocked and the user is locking it again.  
        setLocked(true);
      }
    }
    else
    {
        // Key has been released (used for debounce)
        newKey = true;
    }
}

void setLocked(boolean locked)
{
    if (locked)
    {
        position = 0;
        digitalWrite(redpin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(greenpin, LOW);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(redpin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(greenpin, HIGH);
    }
}
```

Once unlocked, all you have to do is press any key to lock it again.

Resources:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad

Comment: This is wide-open to powerline/timing attacks. Don't  "grade" the pin until all 4 digits have been received. as is, I can quickly tell if the left-most digit is correct, then work my way over to the right in under 36 guesses.

Comment: Agreed, however the OP is a beginner and I wanted to keep it simple and as close to his original code as possible.